# Зачем нужен отрицательный margin и как он используется?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Зачем нужен отрицательный margin?

Comment: чтобы делать отрицательные отступы

Answer (score 1):

Многие считают что это гавнокод, однако, даже знаменитый фреймворк "bootstrap" для формирования своей сетки использует отрицательные марджины

Есть полезные "фишки" с отрицательными марджинами, которые позволяют, к примеру, сделать мнимый отступ при клике на якорь, для того что бы немного сместиться от объекта, к которому перемещаешься при клике на якорь (бывает полезно когда меню "прилипающее" и перекрывает собой объект при клике на ссылку-якорь) Например так:

```
 #link-C {
    padding-top: 55px;
    margin-top: -55px;
    -webkit-background-clip: content-box;
    background-clip: content-box;
 }
```

Comment: в моей практике верстки никогда не требовался отрицательный `margin`/`padding`. Приведите больше примеров.

Comment: кто эти "многие"?

Comment: bootstrap это тоже "гавнокод" так-то, нормальные верстальщики терпеть не могут bootstrap

Comment: отрицательного `padding` не существует

Comment: @vantal да, вы совершенно правы, поправил ответ